# artisan db:seed does not work and does not print an error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

My seeder Class code is as follows:

```
    <?php


use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;





class CategoryTableSeeder extends  Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {

     DB::table('categories')->delete();

     $cats = ['math', 'physics', 'calculus', 'eletronics', 'etc etc'];

            foreach ($cats as $cat)
            {
                Category::create(['category' => $cat]);

            }   


    }
}
```

When I try to seed it using the following command on CLI:

> php artisan db:seed

Nothing happens with no error. What might be wrong with this?
I am seeing similar discussion on [Github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2198) but finding no solution. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `php artisan db:seed --class=CategoryTableSeeder`

If you want to always run this seed add `$this->call('CategoryTableSeeder');` in the DatabaseSeeder